# Why isn't this alternative to the deprecated Factory.set_creation_function working with nosetests?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, nose

Factory Boy deprecated set_creation_function (see [ChangeLog 2.6.1](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changelog.html)) and recommends that developers

> Replace factory.set_creation_function(SomeFactory, creation_function)
>   with an override of the _create() method of SomeFactory

I have i) a number of derivative factory classes and ii) my db session instantiated in another module so I tried replacing the working example from https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt with the second code block below. PyCharm is warning me that the "db" import is not being used, so I suspect it might not be being dereferenced properly when I set [sqlalchemy_session](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/orms.html#factory.alchemy.SQLAlchemyOptions.sqlalchemy_session)?

#### Working with nosetests 1.3.7 (but FactoryBoy's set_creation_function is now deprecated):

```
from myapp.core import db

def create_sqlalchemy_model_function(class_to_create, *args, **kwargs):
    entity = class_to_create(**kwargs)
    db.session.add(entity)
    db.session.commit()
    return entity

Factory.set_creation_function(create_sqlalchemy_model_function)
```

#### Not working with nosetests 2.x  (looking like db is not being referenced properly?)

```
from factory.alchemy import SQLAlchemyModelFactory as Factory
from myapp.core import db

class Factory():
    class Meta:
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session

    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        entity = model_class(*args, **kwargs)
        db.session.add(entity)
        db.session.commit()
        return entity
```

Answer (score 5):

Two major issues with your sample not-working code:

- the class should be derived from `SQLAlchemyModelFactory` class
- the `_create()` method should be defined as `classmethod`

Fixed version:

```
from factory.alchemy import SQLAlchemyModelFactory as Factory
from myapp.core import db

class MyFactory(Factory):
    class Meta:
        sqlalchemy_session = db.session

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        entity = model_class(*args, **kwargs)
        db.session.add(entity)
        db.session.commit()
        return entity
```

Here is also a [sample](https://github.com/rbarrois/factory_boy/blob/2eb8242a31f303d36c15b4644c54afb2cef8257e/tests/test_using.py#L83) of the model factory overriding the `_create()` method.